# REDSHIFT Regex for finding multiple strings within text and returning TRUE or FALSE

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a REGEX that would return TRUE or FALSE when one of four (or more) alphanumeric strings are present in the text together or alone. But if any other word is present then it should return FALSE.

Those string can go in a different orders, many combinations, can occur multiple times also.

I am using REDSHIFT.

Examples - we are looking for abc123, def456, ghi789, jkl123

abc123, def456 - TRUE
def456, abc123 - TRUE
abc123, def456, ghi789, jkl123 - TRUE
abc123, def456, abc123, jkl123 - TRUE
abc123, def456, abc123, other123 - FALSE
other567 - FALSE
abc123, other123, jkl123 - FALSE

Is there a way to this in REGEX?